# Override default window Minimize button logic

Tags: c#, .net, windows, maui

Is there some way to override default window Minimize button logic? I need it to add `window.Hide()` into it, so that my window would be hidden the same time it would be minimized.

I have found [this](https://blog.verslu.is/maui/full-screen-disable-minimize-maximize-for-net-maui-windows-apps/) article, but I am struggling to somehow get this hooked to window minimize logic in Windows.

This can be used to Hide and Show window from `ViewModel` for example:

```
private void OnShowHideWindow()
{
  var window = Application.Current?.MainPage?.Window;
  if (window == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (this.IsWindowVisible)
  {
    window.Hide();
  }
  else
  {
    window.Show();
  }
  this.IsWindowVisible = !this.IsWindowVisible;
}
```

Comment: Try override AppWindow.Presenter with a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spin further with Zhang's answer (great answer by the way), you don't need those Introp calls. If you want this in your app, put it in the App() and do it as easy as this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
#endif
...
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
    {
#if WINDOWS
        var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
        var appWindow = nativeWindow.GetAppWindow();
        if (appWindow is not null)
        {
            appWindow.Changed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (appWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter)
                {
                    if (args.DidPresenterChange && overlappedPresenter.State == OverlappedPresenterState.Minimized)
                    {
                        appWindow.Hide();
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        nativeWindow.Activate();
                    }
                }
            };
        }

#endif
    });

    MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me, but I got it working only by placing this code into Platforms -> Windows. Otherwise I am getting errors that either 'GetAppWindow' is not found or  'Window.Hide()' window does not implement Hide. I have been trying to use with NotifyIcon, provided solution, but logic for tray icon Hide and Unhide from Tray is getting broken at some point, as it is not Unhiding window on a first click. Need to investigate further what might be an issue. However this is topic for another question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Fantastic. Great to hear. Did you add `using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;` in the App.xaml.cs because that is where the extenstion `GetAppWindow` is. `Hide()` is in `using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;`

Answer (score 3):

You can try to detect the window changed event to do that.

Override the MainPage's OnHandlerChanged event or you can also put the code in the window created event like the blog you provided did:

```
 protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
            Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
            Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
            Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
          var presenter = appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter;
          appWindow.Changed += (sender, args) =>
          {
            if(appWindow.IsVisible == true && args.DidPresenterChange == true && presenter.State == Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenterState.Minimized )
            {
               appWindow.Hide();
               // when the app minimized this line will be called
            }
          };  
#endif
    }
```

Comment: I had to pick up another answer, got it working only by placing code into Platforms -> Windows. Otherwise I am getting errors that either 'GetAppWindow' is not found or 'Window.Hide()' window does not implement Hide. It was wrapped into '#if WINDOWS' anyway got an error. Do not know why. I have upvoted this anyway.

Comment: I saw the code in your question and you used `Application.Current?.MainPage?.Window`, so I post the code without testing. I think you know the api aboout hiding window. The key of my answer is how to `Override default window Minimize button logic`. In addition, I have tested it. Just put the code in the first page loaded in your project (maybe not mainpage) and it worked. @10101